# Run a non electron executable inside electron window

Tags: electron, executable

I'm new to Electron and I'd like to run a non electron executable inside my main window. Is it possible to do that?

Here is my code:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 860, height: 645})
mainWindow.loadURL('https://url.com/')

const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('C:\\test\\content.exe', {cwd: 'C:\\test\\'}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track except you need to do:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process').execFile;
```

Instead of:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
```

[`execFile` docs here.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)