# Application launcher using an Electron jS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I'm creating an application launcher with HTML/CSS/JS using electron JS.

For each application I have an `a href` tag which redirects to the path on the application.

If I put a normal link in `a href`, you go normally to the destined website.

If I put an executable path in the `a href`, the link doesn't open the application.

**I tried my projet in firefox and thankfully by using this plugin [addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/) , I was able to launch directly applications.**

How do I launch applications from my project in Electron JS? I mean multiple applications and not just a single one.

```
<div class="1"><a href="file:///myPathToFile.exe">Application 1</a></div>
<div class="2"><a href="file:///myPathToFile2.exe">Application 2</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) and [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer), sending a message from the page using a function.

*HTML*

Instead of using **a tag**, I think you could do that:

```
<div class="1">
<span onclick="openApp" value="file:///myPathToFile.exe">Application 1</span>
</div>
```

*JS Script*

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

function openApp(event) {
const path = event.target.value;
  IpcRenderer.sendSync('open-app', path)
}
```

*And in your Electron file:*

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('open-app', (e, path) => {
  const child = execFile(path, {cwd: 'C:\\test\\'}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
return stdout;
});
  e.returnValue = child;
});
```

Took it from here:

[Run a non electron executable inside electron window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715989/run-a-non-electron-executable-inside-electron-window)

Hope that you won't give up, your project seems so cool. If it's unclear let me know

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! But I tried and unfortunately didn't work. I tried your code exactly without any modification except the path of the executable. I tried also with " a href " tag instead on span. The reason I'm using a href is because I have other CSS and JS codes bases on it.

Comment: Also the `span` tag is non-clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using electron, you can use nodeJS apis as well. NodeJS has the `child_process` module which could accomplish what you want.

Here is an example

```js
const childProcess = require("child_process");

// Attach event handler to all application links. You can change the selector to something more precise if you wish.
document.querySelectorAll("a[href]").forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        childProcess.spawn(elem.getAttribute("href")); // spawns the executable with the href on the a element

    // WARNING: Doing something like this could potentially expose your computer to hackers.
    // Make sure the href attributes are trusted and do not come from the web. Hackers could potentially use the href attribute to launch malware on your computer.
    });
});
```

More details on the `child_process` module: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Edit:
Make sure you execute this once the DOM nodes have loaded. You can do something like this to achive it:

```js
$(() => {
    // code over here
});
```

Or if not using jquery:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // code over here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I may be wrong but I placed this code inside my script.js file but didn't work. I initialised childProcess in main.js also and nothing.

Comment: @Seito Kimbo Make sure you are executing this script once all the dom elements have loaded. You can used jquery for this: `$(() => { /* code here */ });`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand well what you mean :/ . Can you direectly edit your post with modification if you have any ?

Comment: I don't know man but it didn't work. I will have to thank you for your effort. I guess I just don't know what to place where. I tried placing your code in main.js and script.js but none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to launch your application/file with default window's program than in that case you can use shell.openPath, below is the working code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World!</title>
<!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="1"><a href="#" onclick="openFile('C:\\folder\\path_to_exe')">Application 1</a> 
</div>
<script>
    function openFile(filepath){
    const shell = require('electron').shell;
    shell.openPath(filepath);
    }
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Note - Don't use forward slash in path, use double-backward slash for this.

Comment: Yes I want to open them normally with Windows. The question is, how do I associate the function to each `a href` tag I have ?

Comment: are you able to alert or console.log the file path you're passing to function?

Comment: I'm very sorry I didn't understand what did you meant ..

Comment: <script>
function openFile(filepath){ alert(filepath);}</script>  can you reproduce the string output from this.

Comment: use file path in format like 'E://workstation//app.exe' i.e don't use backward slash instead of it use forward slash.

Comment: and also don't use 'file:' keyword in path directly start with directory like in above example.

Comment: The alert is working showing the path of the file. I tried with forward slashes and removed file too and didn't work.

Comment: If you're using this approach and the file is missing then there should be error dialogue representing missing file with path or may be some error is there.

Comment: None :/ I think you can try your code and perhaps see if it's working on your side ?

Comment: can you provide your anchor tag code, i would like to see what you're passing? it will help in debugging

Comment: `<div class="1"><a href="#" onclick="openFile('D://Games Bond//The Messenger//TheMessenger.exe')">Application 1</a></div>`

Comment: the issue is something else, the code is working fine on my system...hope you will get your solution :/

Comment: try to open other file like .txt extension check if it works

Comment: Not working too. Can you upload your whole repository on github so I can inspect the code ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think electron has removed shell.openItem from its documentation and is no longer supported...